# Showing error during using overwritepermission

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was expecting to give everyone 10 sec to type and then remove the permission but the script is not working.

```js
if (message.channel.id === "channel id") {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has("everyone's id")) {
        setInterval(function () { 
            message.channel.send("start").then(channel => {
                channel.overwritePermissions([{
                    id: message.guild.id,
                    allow: 0x00000800
                }]).then(channel => {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        channel.overwritePermissions([{
                            id: message.guild.id,
                            deny: 0x00000800
                        }])                        
                    }, 10000);
                });   
            })
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

This error is showing in the terminal.

````
(node:14500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: channel.overwritePermissions is not a function
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord bot\BOT SHOT\commands\repeat1.js:9:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) function returns a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) not a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel). The correct code would be:

```js
.then(() => {
    message.channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
      id: message.guild.id,
      allow: [0x00000800]
    },
])
```

Comment: Thanks, bro now it's working, but now it changes it all permission to null. I think I should change .overwritePremissions to .updatePermission.

Comment: `updatePermission` isn't an existing function. I think the reason it didn't work is that the `allow` parameter has to be an array (so I added the `[]`).

Comment: oh, I wanna say .updateoverwrites, and thanks again.

Comment: now it's not allow to add a role for that channel permission and it still changes to null in discord.